# Parallax effect white space

Tags: javascript, jquery

My parallax effect adds white space to the top of the page, when scrolling.

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('background-position', 'left ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
 });
</script>
```

**No scroll:**
[image: No Scroll]

**When scrolling:**
[image: When scrolling]

Comment: Please post more inofrmation and exampe (like jsFiddle link).

Comment: It properly should be minus pixels:
var scrolledY = -1 * $(window).scrollTop();

Comment: I think you should set handler for mouse weel event. Not scroll event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code adds a vertical offset in pixels on scroll so it goes right: when the image shifted down there is nothing to display at the top so you need to set `background-repeat` or control the offset value and avoid to set new value after it goes out of bounds. And also you need to multiply scrolledY value by -1 to makes image on a background moving up on a page scroll down like in a parallax effect.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolledY = -1 * $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('background-position', 'left ' + (scrolledY) + 'px');
 });
```

Also you can control the speed of background offset by division of vertical value by two or something like that. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/9pkrxjh0/